# add multiple Effects on ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml

I am trying to add multiple Effects (more than 2) to an ImageView.
2 Effects are no problem with: `effect1.setInput(Effect effect2) and imageView.setEffect(effect1)`

But how can I do it with 3 or more Effects?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work just fine (the order matters):

```
effect2.setInput(effect3);
effect1.setInput(effect2);
imageView.setEffect(effect1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me couples of months before

```
ImageView imView = new ImageView();
PerspectiveTransform pTrans = new PerspectiveTransform(100, 110, 400, 160, 400, 940, 100, 1060);
Reflection ref = new Reflection();
pTrans.setInput(ref);
imView.setEffect(pTrans);
```

References

https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/12/javafx-how-to-apply-multiple-effects-to-a-node/